# Games rendering red foam all over objects

Tags: technical-issues

In a large number of games on my PC I have had issues with games rendering improperly. It is extremely hard to describe, so here is a picture of this in one of the many games it is occurring in:

[image: this is a screenshot I took in the game dirty bomb displaying the issue]

This never happened until I recently had my computer re-imaged to get rid of the hundreds of viruses I had. There was also a drop in FPS after the re-image as well. I have tried lowering graphics setting to the minimum and this still happens.

Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Just a guess, but after having your system re-imaged, have you updated your graphics drivers?

Comment: @TrentHawkins i checked and the drivers a up to date

Comment: I would try uninstalling your graphics driver completely, rebooting your machine, then reinstalling the graphics driver. Also make sure that if you have a graphics card and a built-in graphics accelerator that you disable the graphics accelerator to ensure that your applications are using the graphics card.

Answer (score 3):

In the past, I worked in a segment of the computer industry where we used naked LCD panels, independent from the control circuitry. (I'm not talking about a graphics card; the panel controller is a discrete component.) I've seen patterns like that when the controller was bad - either overheated or with manufacturing defects.

Unfortunately, in retail applications, the controller is not something you can easily separate from the panel for testing. Your next best bet is to test with an entirely different display.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'm not an expert, but I have an idea...

It looks like your graphics card is rendering the model wireframes for some reason.  You said that this is a screenshot, so that would indicate to me that this is being pulled directly from the graphic card's memory, which gives me the impression that there's nothing wrong with your display.

If this happens more consistently with 3D games than with 2D games then I'm also getting the impression that you might have a corrupted runtime library(s) associated with graphics rendering somewhere.  That's generally bad news, but it is fixable.

I don't know what that hypothetical library(s) could be, but you might be able to find some specific result if you look at all of the files opened by each game that's malfunctioning and find the file(s) that all of them have in common.

You should be able to re-install those files and get the games to work.

However, since I'm not an expert, I would recommend that you show this problem and potential solution to someone who's proficient (to say the least) with troubleshooting these kinds of errors.

TL;DR Talk to an expert.